# Posting back the ID of a row from a table with data that has been retrieved from SQL

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to get the ID of a row and the value of a checkbox to post back to the page if the checkbox is changed i.e. checked or unchecked.

I have managed to get it to post back using different id's for each element such as `checkbox_$rowid` so that it's not pulling the first ID and gets the correct ID.

The issue arises when I go to use the post data from the form as obviously the ID of the row will be different, the row id is being used as an identifier at the end of the variable names, so I want to get the ID in a separate variable without posting the page twice.

I have a feeling this will be an ajax job but I'm not very confident in ajax so all help is appreciated.

Here is the html/php

```
<input class='form-control' type='checkbox' value='1' id='cbStatus_$rowID' onchange='validate($rowID)'>
<input type='number' id='txtStatus_$rowID' name='txtStatus_$rowID' class='form-control' value='1' hidden>
<input type='number' id='txtID' name='txtID' class='form-control' hidden>
<button type='submit' value='Submit' name='btnSubmit1_$rowID' id='btnSubmit1_$rowID' hidden>...</button>
</form><label class='form-check-label' for='flexCheckDefault'>";
```

Here is the javascript

```
function validate(rowID) {
    var row = rowID;
    var cbStatus = document.getElementById("cbStatus_" + row);
    if (cbStatus.checked) {
        alert("checked");
        var txtStatus = document.getElementById("txtStatus_" + row);
        var txtID = document.getElementById("txtID");
        txtStatus.value = cbStatus.value;
        txtID.value = row;
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit1_" + row).click();
        document.getElementById("btnSubmitID").click();
    } else {
        alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
        var txtStatus = document.getElementById("txtStatus_" + row);
        txtStatus.value = 1;
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit1_" + row).click();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by: _"I'm trying to .... post back to the page ..."_. Do you mean you want to send a message from the browser to a PHP script on your server? I doubt this because you also say: _"I have managed to get it to post back ..."_ when you're referring to code that clearly doesn't post anything back to the server. What I'm trying to say is that the language you use is confusing. We only have the text in your question to go on, try to be as explicit and precise as possible. I think you're a native English speaker, so you should be able to do this.

Comment: What is `txtID2`? ... there is no element in the HTML with this id.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I need the ID of the row to be posted back to the page that the form is on that submitted the data. However I also need the value of the checkbox within that form. The checkbox is in a row within a table hence the issue with the data. The code does post back, as btnSubmit is 'clicked' in the javascript code submitting the form.

Comment: @PaulT. Apologies that was another textbox I was testing with, code has been fixed.

Comment: Remember that the row is part of the page, so nothing can be "posted back", everything happens within the same page. If you talk about "posting back" you imply two entities, one the server, the other the client, and the client sends something back to the server. So when a form is submitted you can indeed talk about posting things back. Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75532860/edit) your question so this becomes clear to other readers as well?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Currently won't allow me to, but as soon as I can, I will.

Comment: `<input type='number' id='txtID' name='txtID' class='form-control' hidden>` - this should not be repeated in every row your are generating for your form, but be contained in the form only once. You are already writing the row ID into that field in your JavaScript function - only because of duplicate IDs, you are writing it into the _first_ field with that ID, and so you lose it when the data gets submitted, because the parameter gets overwritten by the _following_ field(s) that have the same name.

Comment: And you can make that `type="hidden"`, and leave out the `hidden` attribute. Using `type='number'` has no benefit here - because you are not showing this to the user, so any UI that "comes with" a number input field, is of no use to begin with here.

Comment: You cannot edit your question? I didn't know that. How weird. Are you sure?